# Debug APK won't launch on physical phone

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I recently generated the debug APK for my application but after installing on phone it doesn't show up in the application menu of my phone ,only in settings -> applications and once clicked, there is no 'open' option.
I tried with another application and all works well but not for the first application. It runs when I use USB debugging and run from Android Studio but it doesn't install.
please help.
Here's my build.gradle , I'll give more information but it's my first time working on a big project alone I truly am lost.

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.github.node-gradle.node'
    id("com.apollographql.apollo").version("2.5.9")
}
apply plugin: 'com.github.node-gradle.node'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
def  cognitoWebClient
def apikeyPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("secrets.properties")
def apikeyProperties = new Properties()
apikeyProperties.load(new FileInputStream(apikeyPropertiesFile))
android {
    compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "beatview.android.huru"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        buildConfigField("String", "cognitoWebClient", apikeyProperties['cognitoWebClient'])
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true


    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
   }

   dependencies {
    implementation("app.futured.donut:donut:2.2.0")
    implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:swipeable-button:0.1.0'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.4.0'
    
}
```

Edit:
My manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="beatview.android.huruapp">
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
<queries>
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider" /> <!-- allows app to access Facebook app features -->
    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.orca.provider.PlatformProvider" /> <!-- allows sharing to Messenger app -->
</queries>

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name=
            "android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
    </intent>
</queries>
<application
    android:name=".AlarmRX"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Global Broadcast Receiver -->
    <receiver android:name=".AppGlobalReceiver"/>

    <!-- For retrieving the broadcast sent by the system when the alarm is triggered -->
    <receiver android:name=".helpers.notif.AlarmReceiver" />

    <!-- For listening to device reboot to reschedule alarms -->
    <receiver android:name=".helpers.notif.BootReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name=".splashScreen"
        android:exported="false" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.activities.HostedUIRedirectActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="huruprojectffdd5a72-ffdd5a72-local.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:scheme="https://huruprojectffdd5a72-ffdd5a72-local.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
</application>
```

Comment: Edit your question and post your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Certain entries in there define what activities are shown as icons you can start.

Comment: Those `<data android:scheme` entries are defect. The scheme is just the prefix like `https` but never a full url. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element

Comment: Thank you! It works now.